# Iterate over the union of a set and a number efficiently and elegantly in Julia

Tags: garbage-collection, set, julia, union, allocation

I ran into the issue of having to iterate millions of times over the union of a sets and a number in Julia. I have encountered two solutions: one elegant but inefficient, and the other efficient but not elegant.

MWE: Consider the following three functions that, given one set of integers and another integer, compute the sum of the elements in the union:

```
function f(a::Set{Int64}, b::Int64)::Int64
    return sum(union(a, b))
end
```

```
function g(a::Set{Int64}, b::Int64)::Int64
    s = sum(a)
    if !in(b, a) s += b end
    return s
end
```

Now, let us consider the folowing calls to the functions `f` and `g` (the outputs below represent the behavior after precompilation for both functions):

```
julia> a = Set{Int64}(rand(-10000000 : 10000000, 10000000))
julia> b = maximum(a) + 1
```

```
julia> @benchmark f(a, b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 15 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  325.095 ms … 348.911 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 4.64%
 Time  (median):     333.346 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.17%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   337.121 ms ±   8.365 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  2.14% ± 2.38%

  █     ▁          ▁█ ▁▁                    █    ▁   ▁    █   ▁  
  █▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁██▁██▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█ ▁
  325 ms           Histogram: frequency by time          349 ms <

 Memory estimate: 144.00 MiB, allocs estimate: 11.

julia> @benchmark g(a, b)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 76 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  65.334 ms …  69.013 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     66.057 ms               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   66.216 ms ± 595.005 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

        ▄  ▂▂▂ ▄ █   ▆                                          
  ▄▁▁▁▁▄█▁████▄█▆██▄▄██▆█▁▁▁▆▁▆█▁▄▁▄▁█▆▁▄▁▁▁▄▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▄ ▁
  65.3 ms         Histogram: frequency by time         67.9 ms <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

As you can see, the function `g` is more efficient both in terms of GC and time, but the body of the function also uglier.

**Question: is there a way to achieve the elegancy of function `f` while achieving the performance of `g`? More specifically, I am thinking of something tat would allow to iterate over such an union without having to allocate a new Set**

I tried both implementations and I am currently keeping the one that resembles to function `g` for the sake of efficiency

Comment: There is a very simple solution that is as fast as `g` and as elegant as `f`. There's a caveat, though, it will modify your set, so be aware of that: `sum(push!(a, b))`. In most cases, I would use @Bill's answer or your own function `g`.

Comment: Than you. The issue in my case with that solution is that I will need the set `a` a million times. So I would have to do `pop!(a, b)` right after which I am afraid will reduce the efficiency

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a cleaner version of g(), consider

```
h(a, b) = sum(a) + b * !(b in a)
```

which uses the fact that the boolean !(b in a) is 0 if false, 1 if true. Any addition of b to the set is going to check for b in a to prevent duplicate elements anyway, and occasionally adding b to a will trigger an automatic allocation if the set's size is at an edge of its memory allotment (not here though).

Comment: Not only shorter, but also removing an unnecessary branch!

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to say that in the actual code, it is not a sum that is made but a more elaborate operation. But for a simple operation like sum, I agree this will work and is much more elegant than `g`